# Format ignore non important underscore variables

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to print the results as a form of aX^2+bX+c and I don't want the variables to be printed if it's value is non important(starts with _) or =1 or -1

```
polynomial_string(A, B, C, PolyString) :-
    % Generate polynomial coefficients
    rA(A, Sg2, Coef2, Var2, Expo2),
    rB(B, A, Sg1, Coef1, Var1),
    rC(C, A, B, Sg0, Coef0),
    % Build string from coefficients
    format(atom(PolyString), '~w~w~w^~w~w~w~w~w~w', [Sg2, Coef2, Var2, Expo2, Sg1, Coef1, Var1, Sg0, Coef0]).
```

If the input is
polynomial_string(1, 2, 1, PolyString).
the output should be x^2 + 2x +1

Comment: Can check whether to output an individual number, using e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=var/1

Comment: Are you sure that you want to print the formula in a format that cannot be read back by Prolog?